# Send props to frameworkComponents (ag-grid) with Vue

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I would like to pass a props to frameworkComponents, I am using Vue. Any idea how I could do it?

file grid.vue

```
<ag-grid-vue
      class="ag-theme-balham"
      :gridOptions="gridOptions"
      :rowData="rowData"
      :frameworkComponents="this.frameworkComponents"
      :myprops="this.data"
 ></ag-grid-vue>
```

file myFrameworkComponent.vue

```
props: {
    myprops: {
        type: String,
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this inside of the template is not required. Also accessing props directly is a $ sign in front.

```
<ag-grid-vue
      class="ag-theme-balham"
      :gridOptions="gridOptions"
      :rowData="rowData"
      :frameworkComponents="this.frameworkComponents"
      :myprops="$props"
 ></ag-grid-vue>
```

Comment: Can you add a link to the documentation for this?

Answer (score 0):

In grid.vue, I just define the params inside the columnDef.

```
{
    field: 'helloId',
    headerName: 'Hello',
    filter: "dropdown",
    filterParams: 'this is my message or object',
},
```

After this params is called in the mounted of myFrameworkComponent.vue:

```
mounted: function() {
    myprops: this.params.colDef.filterParams
},
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you gone through the getting started?
https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-getting-started/

Here is a working example for you:
https://codesandbox.io/s/9ovqv28y2y

Comment: The OP's question is about passing props to a Vue component used to display data in a cell (ie: FrameworkComponent). You're example has nothing to do with that, just a vanilla implementation of `ag-grid-vue`.